# MAAS Upgrade from 2.0.0 beta 3 to 2.0.0 beta 4

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, maas

UBUNTU 16.04

How can I Upgrade MAAS from 2.0.0 **beta 3** to 2.0.0 **beta 4**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you should follow http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/install.html#maas-packages-and-repositories with a slight change:

```
# add developement branch instead of stable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maas/next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If you'll be able to drop PPA source any time later with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:maas/next
```